# Brezis' exercise 8.6.3: is there a shorter approach?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, alternative-proof

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.6.1** Let $I=(0, 1)$ and $p \in (1, \infty]$.
>
> 1. Check that $W^{2, p} (I) \subset C^1 (\bar I)$ with compact injection.
> 2. Deduce that for $\varepsilon >0$ there is $C=C(\varepsilon, p)$ such that
>    $$
>    \| u' \|_{L^\infty} + \| u \|_{L^\infty} \le \varepsilon \| u'' \|_{L^p} + C \| u \|_{L^1},
>    \quad u \in W^{2, p} (I).
>    $$
> 3. Let $q \in [1, \infty)$. Prove that for $\varepsilon >0$ there is $C=C(\varepsilon, q)$ such that
>    $$
>    \| u' \|_{L^q} + \| u \|_{L^\infty} \le \varepsilon \| u'' \|_{L^1} + C \| u \|_{L^1},
>    \quad u \in W^{2, 1} (I).
>    $$

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you have a check on it? My approach is quite long. Is there a shorter alternative?

---

We need an auxiliary result, i.e.,

> - [Exercise 6.12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726063/brezis-exercise-6-12-a-lemma-of-j-l-lions) Let $X,Y,Z$ be real Banach spaces with corresponding norms $|\cdot|_X, |\cdot|_Y, |\cdot|_Z$. Assume that $X \subset Y$ with *compact* injection and that $Y \subset Z$ with *continuous* injection. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
>   $$
>   |u|_Y \le \varepsilon |u|_X + C_\varepsilon |u|_Z
>   \quad \forall u \in X.
>   $$
> - **Exercise 8.5.3** Let $q \in [1, \infty)$. For $\varepsilon >0$ there is $C=C(\varepsilon, q)$ such that
>   $$
>   \| u \|_{L^q} \le \varepsilon \| u' \|_{L^1} + C \| u \|_{L^1},
>   \quad u \in W^{1, 1} (I).
>   $$

3. 

We apply **exercise 8.5.3** for $u'$ and get
$$
\| u' \|_{L^q} \le \varepsilon \| u'' \|_{L^1} + C \| u' \|_{L^1}.
$$

By [Theorem 8.8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763660/brezis-theorem-8-8-how-to-get-the-inequality-u-l-inftyi-leq-c-u) (in the same book), the injection $W^{1, 1}(I) \subset C(\bar{I})$ is continuous. Then there is $c>0$ such that
$$
\| u \|_{L^\infty} \le c \| u \|_{L^1} + c\| u' \|_{L^1}.
$$

I have [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784378/let-i-0-1-the-injection-w2-1i-subset-w1-1i-is-compact) that the injection $W^{2, 1}(I) \subset W^{1, 1}(I)$ is compact. We apply **exercise 6.12** with $X = W^{2, 1} (I), Y= W^{1, 1}(I)$ and $Z= L^1 (I)$ and get
$$
\begin{align*}
\| u \|_{L^1} + \| u' \|_{L^1}  &\le \varepsilon' (\| u \|_{L^1} + \| u' \|_{L^1} + \| u'' \|_{L^1}) + C' \| u \|_{L^1},
\quad u \in W^{2, 1} (I).
\end{align*}
$$

It follows that
$$
\| u' \|_{L^1}  \le \varepsilon_2  \| u'' \|_{L^1} + C_2 \| u \|_{L^1},
\quad u \in W^{2, 1} (I).
$$

Finally,
$$
\begin{align*}
\| u' \|_{L^q}  + \| u \|_{L^\infty} &\le (\varepsilon \| u'' \|_{L^1} + C \| u' \|_{L^1}) + (c \| u \|_{L^1} + c\| u' \|_{L^1}) \\
& = \varepsilon \| u'' \|_{L^1} + c \| u \|_{L^1} +(C+c)  \| u' \|_{L^1} \\
&\le \varepsilon \| u'' \|_{L^1} +c \| u \|_{L^1} + (C+c) ( \varepsilon _2 \| u'' \|_{L^1} + C_2 \| u \|_{L^1}) \\
& = (\varepsilon +C \varepsilon_2+c\varepsilon_2) \| u'' \|_{L^1} + (c+cC_2+CC_2) \| u \|_{L^1}, 
\quad u \in W^{2, 1} (I).
\end{align*}
$$

Because $\varepsilon_2$ can be chosen independently of $\varepsilon, C$. The quantity $(\varepsilon +C \varepsilon_2+c\varepsilon_2)$ can be arbitrarily small. The claim then follows.