# Brezis' exercise 8.23.5: how to find the best constant $C_k$ such that $\|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq C_k\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$ and $k >0$. I'm trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.23**
>
> 1. Given $f \in L^1(I)$ prove that there exists a unique $u \in H_0^1(I)$ satisfying
>    $$
>    (1) \quad
>    \int_I u' v'+k \int_I u v=\int_I f v \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(I) .
>    $$
> 2. Show that $u \in W^{2,1}(I)$.
> 3. Prove that
>    $$
>    \|u\|_{L^1} \leq \frac{1}{k}\|f\|_{L^1} .
>    $$
> 4. Assume now that $f \in L^p(I)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Show that there exists a constant $\delta>0$ independent of $k$ and $p$, such that
>    $$
>    \|u\|_{L^p} \leq \frac{1}{k+\delta / (p p')}\|f\|_{L^p},
>    $$
>    where $p'$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$.
> 5. Prove that if $f \in L^{\infty}(I)$, then
>    $$
>    \|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq C_k\|f\|_{L^{\infty}},
>    $$
>    and find the best constant $C_k$.

I have proved the inequality in (5.) below. Could you explain how to find the best constant $C_k$?

---

It follows from $(1)$ that $\int_I [ |u'|^2 + k|u|^2 ] = \int_I f u$. By Hölder's inequality, $\alpha \| u \|_{H^1}^2 \le \|f\|_{L^1} \|u\|_{L^\infty}$ where $\alpha := \min \{1, k\}$. By [Theorem 8.8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763660/brezis-theorem-8-8-how-to-get-the-inequality-u-l-inftyi-leq-c-u) (in the same book), there is a constant $C>0$ such that $\|u\|_{L^\infty} \le C \| u \|_{H^1}$. Then
$$
\| u \|_{H^1} \le \frac{C}{\alpha} \|f\|_{L^1} \le \frac{C}{\alpha} \|f\|_{L^\infty},
$$
which implies
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty} \le \frac{C^2}{\alpha} \|f\|_{L^\infty}.
$$